# MS visual studio 2013 SDL not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, dependencies, sdl

I am using SDL in my project but I ran into a problem. I followed a tutorial on how to include SDL in MS visual studio [here](http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-visual-studio/)but it did not help. Here are the steps that I took.

First, I added the SDL input directory in C/C++ / General "Additional input directories" block:

[image]

Second, I added the SDL lib directory in Linker / General "Additional library directories" block:

[image]

Third, I added SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib to the "Additional dependencies" section under Linker / input:

[image]

And last, I set the subsystem section under Linker / system to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE):

[image]

This did not work, however, when I tried to run the test code that was supplied by the tutorial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

because I got these build errors when I debugged:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>start.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetError referenced in function _SDL_main
1>start.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
1>start.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\holger\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Game\Debug\Project2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I thought that I followed the tutorial well, but apparently not. Please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Cheers engineers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be that you're building a 32-bit application, but pointing to the 64-bit libraries.

Your error:

`Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug Win32`

But your library directory that you've set has `x64` as the subdirectory.

Comment: Now it says that SDL2.dll is missing from computer even though I saw it in input/x86... sorry that I am carrying on and on about this

Comment: Missing DLL's fall outside the build stage.  A simple fix is to install the DLL in a directory either on the PATH, or in your application's executable directory.  Otherwise, follow what Windows goes through to resolve DLL's:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx